# Implement feedly API using Scribe

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, scribe

I am trying to implement Feedly API using Scribe.

For requesting the access token, they have an additional parameter `grant_type` to be included in the POST request to `POST /v3/auth/token` as documented in:

http://developer.feedly.com/v3/auth/

How do I take this into account?

The implementation of [OAuth20ServiceImpl](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/scribe/oauth/OAuth20ServiceImpl.java) suggests that these it only submits these parameters:
* CLIENT_ID
* CLIENT_SECRET
* CODE
* REDIRECT_URI
* SCOPE

I am getting error that `grant_type` is null while calling `getAccessToken` because of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is subclassing [OAuth2ServiceImpl](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/scribe/oauth/OAuth20ServiceImpl.java) and overriding the sign method to add the missing parameter.

Then from your `FeedlyApi` class (that inherits `DefaultApi20`, I assume), override the [createService](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/scribe/builder/api/DefaultApi20.java#L67) method to return your service subclass.

This is a bit of a hassle, and maybe it's easier to do it from scratch. OAuth 2.0 having so many variations and being significantly easier than 1.0a is the reason why scribe is going to be 1.0a only in future versions.

Comment: Thanks. For now, authorization_type is a constant in Feedly Api, so I just included it as  a part of initial Url.

Comment: Cool, have fun with that!